# How much does irrelevant information in an image affect the learning process of CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have a CNN for Alzheimer detection on MRI data. The MRI's are 3D 1.5T scans and the skull is very visible (a premade dataset from ADNI1 year 3). I've been trying to adapt skull stripping but haven't succeeded so decided to run my model without skull stripping.

The results are rather confusing to me. As can be seen in the images attached, the model doesn't have a normal learning curve. I tried changing parameters of the model, adding more layers and drop-out regularization, but I either got this random learning curve or a constant one (the accuracy and loss wouldn't change throughout the epochs), also the accuracy is very low and remains to be very low (it's binary classification).

[image: Accuracy], 
[image: Loss]

I was wondering how much the input data affects the learning process of the model. I learned that preprocessing isn't always necessary for neural networks since the network subtracts the features itself, but these results got me question that. So my question: how much does irrelevant data (the skull in my case) affect the learning process of a neural network?

Edit: my model added

```
#hot-one labeling
Y = np.load('y_array.npy')
X = np.load('images_array.npy')
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)

#train-test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, dummy_y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

print(X_train.shape , X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
[out:] (718, 192, 192, 160) (180, 192, 192, 160) (718, 2) (180, 2)

batch_size = 64
epochs = 40
num_classes =2

AD_model = Sequential()
AD_model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='linear',input_shape=(192,192,160),padding='same'))
AD_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
AD_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same'))
AD_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
AD_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
AD_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
AD_model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
AD_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))                  
AD_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
AD_model.add(Flatten())
AD_model.add(Dense(256, activation='linear'))
AD_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))                  
AD_model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))

AD_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
AD_model.summary()

Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 192, 192, 64)      92224     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_1 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 192, 192, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 96, 96, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 96, 96, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_2 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 96, 96, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 48, 48, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 48, 48, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_3 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 48, 48, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 24, 24, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 147456)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               37748992  
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_4 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 514       
=================================================================
Total params: 38,210,754
Trainable params: 38,210,754
Non-trainable params: 0

history = AD_model.fit(
    X_train, 
    y_train, 
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: The curves are very confusing. Do you want to share your model?

Comment: There is always no irrelevant data....

Comment: Irrelevant data may affect the model. But it's impossible to say how much. Every data and every model are different. Now, you should really bring enough information to your question. It's not possible to answer anything.

Comment: for skull stripping part, you can use fsl `https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FslInstallation`

Comment: @DanielMöller I added the model I used. I can't give an example of how one of the MRI's I'm working with looks like due to privacy. But an example of a similar image is the second image [here](https://www.mriclinicalcasemap.philips.com/global/case/66/i) (Sagittal 3D T1w FFE)

Comment: Do you really have 160 input channels? :O

Comment: @DanielMöller Yes, it's a 3D image. So the 160 input channels represent each slice of the MRI image (height, width, time/slice). It's a greyscale image, so in this case there is no dimension for color.

Comment: @Pygirl Thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately I'm working on Windows and fsl is only usable for unix systems as I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444272/command-bet-could-not-be-found-on-host-error-while-using-bet-in-fsl-on-windo)

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2D convolutions on 3D images. This might be a huge cause of lack of performance. You're simply discarding one spatial dimension, making it behave as if just features.

The most obvious suggestion here is to make a 3D convolution model.

You're also using 'sigmoid' on two classes for a problem that seems categorical.

### Make the model 3D

Before anything, make `X` 3D:

```
X = X.reshape((-1, 192, 192, 160, 1))
```

Then make your model 3D:

```
AD_model = Sequential()
AD_model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=3,input_shape=(192,192,160,1),padding='same'))
AD_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
AD_model.add(MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2),padding='same'))
AD_model.add(Conv3D(128, 3, activation='linear',padding='same'))
AD_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
AD_model.add(MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2),padding='same'))
AD_model.add(Conv3D(256, 3, activation='linear',padding='same'))
AD_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))                  
AD_model.add(MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2),padding='same'))

#warning, maybe this gets too big and you might need to do more pooling steps 
AD_model.add(Flatten()) 

AD_model.add(Dense(256, activation='linear'))
AD_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))                  
AD_model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
```

### Deal with a categorical problem correctly:

- If you have `y_train.shape == (batch, 2)`, one dimension meaning healthy and another meaning Alzheimer, then you need `activation='softmax'` and `loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'`.
- If you have `y_train.shape == (batch, 1)`, being the value 0 a condition and 1 another condition, then you need `activation='sigmoid'` and `loss = 'binary_crossentropy'`.

### (Test this) Use better kernel initializers for ReLU

It might be interesting to test the `kernel_initializer='he_uniform'` on the layers that use ReLU. This may help speed and convergence. (Don't know if it works well with "leaky" relu, but it might be worth trying)

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I adapted your suggestion and the model is still running (it's halfway done), but the accuracy doesn't seem to get higher than 50% and is even dropping. So it seems like it's acting similar to before.

Comment: Then there may be other things that we can't detect in your code. Maybe your data is incorrectly scaled, maybe your data is just too difficult for this model, maybe there is a bug somewhere else.